# whenever i try to run the website on localhost using wamp it shows database error and unable to acess it

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

this is the code in DB_driver.php in line 140  (the database error i was referring to)

```
class CI_DB_driver {

    var $username;
    var $password;
    var $hostname;
    var $database;
    var $dbdriver       = 'mysql';
    var $dbprefix       = '';
    var $char_set       = 'utf8';
    var $dbcollat       = 'utf8_general_ci';
    var $autoinit       = TRUE;

if ($this->database != '')
        {
            if ( ! $this->db_select())
            {
                log_message('error', 'Unable to select database: '.$this->database);

                if ($this->db_debug)
                {
                    $this->display_error('db_unable_to_select', $this->database);
                }
                return FALSE;
            }
```

Comment: That code does not show the connection to the database server.

Comment: Please post the _exact_ error message you get.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have the mysql extension enabled in php.ini

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
```

make sure your socket name is correct in php.ini

```
mysql.default_socket="MySQL"
```

make sure you can access port 3306 through your firewall (deafult mysql port), try turning your firewall off and trying again. Also make sure mysql is running, depending upon your wamp setup, mysql may not start automatically on reboot without some configuration.

the first thing I normally do is use a mysql client and try to connect to the database on the local host with the full username (ex: user@localhost) and password I'm passing to the PHP function. A lot of the time I've found it's DB permission errors for new users that were created.